# How can I use the value from different activity to the IF statement?

Tags: java, android

I am now trying to make a quiz application, and what I want to do this is that 3 SharedPreferences DB will be chosen by the Image Button that the user tap.
However, the data1 shows Null.
How can I fix this error, my code is missing something?

1. Click ImageButton No1(if 2, then 2) in StartActivity
2. Go to the MainActivity
3. Generate ArrayList from SharedPreference No1 (if 2, then 2)

else statement is working, so not the issue of SharedPreferences
That is why I thought that maybe getting value from different, OR to use that value in IF Statement is the problem.

↓StartActivity

```html
imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                int data1 = 1;
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA", data1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

```html
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

        countLabel = findViewById(R.id.countLabel);
        questionLabel = findViewById(R.id.questionLabel);
        answerBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.answerBtn1);
        answerBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.answerBtn2);
        answerBtn3 = findViewById(R.id.answerBtn3);
        answerBtn4 = findViewById(R.id.answerBtn4);

        //Make questionArray from qDB
        Intent intentTest = getIntent();
        int data1 = intentTest.getIntExtra(StartActivity.EXTRA_DATA, 0);
        if (data1 == 1) {
            //Here DOES NOT WORK
            for (String[] quizDatum : qDB1) {
                //Prepare the nw array
                ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
                //Add QuestionData
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[0]);
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[1]);
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[2]);
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[3]);
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[4]);
                //Add tmpArray to the questionArray
                questionArray1.add(tmpArray);
            }
            showNextQuiz();
        } else {
            //↓Here works
            for (String[] quizDatum : qDB2) {
                //Prepare the nw array
                ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
                //Add QuestionData
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[0]);
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[1]);
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[2]);
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[3]);
                tmpArray.add(quizDatum[4]);
                //Add tmpArray to the questionArray
                questionArray1.add(tmpArray);
            }
            showNextQuiz();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (message.equals("Test")){ the equal method must be used when you check String